# Comparing rasters using Calculate Values in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I have two rasters with the same extents, each with all pixel values of the same value. Raster A has pixel values of 6 and Raster B has pixel values of 3. I know ModelBuilder has the Calculate Values tool that can process rasters with Python.

What code could I use to call these rasters and compare them to produce values?

What I am asking is if it is possible to essentially extract a number from a raster. So I know I can use Raster Calculator to generate a map where every pixel has a value equal to Raster A/Raster B. But I want to generate the number = to Raster A/Raster B so I can use it as an input in Modelbuilder.

Comment: If you want to divide A by B then C = A / B, see the divide operator http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Division/005m000000ms000000/, if you're using this outside of python then you will need to use Raster Calculator http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000 for a GUI front end or the Divide tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000008r000000 in model builder. That's simple enough, but to complicate things, what happens when A != 6 or B != 3? What happens in situations of NoData?

Comment: If you are going to simply divide one by another just use the divide tool, why make your life difficult?